# How can I get faraday/scan to walk an entire DynamoDB table?

Tags: clojure

I am struggling for the Faraday incantation to scan an entire DDB table.  The following function produces output, but returns far fewer results than the 18M records I know are in the table.

```
(far/scan 
  common/client-opts 
  v2-index/layer-table-name
  {:return #{:layer-key :range-key}})
=>
[{:range-key "soil&2015-07-22T15:13:09.101Z&ssurgo&v1", :layer-key "886985&886985"}
 {:range-key "soil&2015-07-29T19:20:09.973Z&ssurgo&v1", :layer-key "886985&886985"}
  ...
 {:range-key "veg&2014-05-29T16:16:31.000Z&true-color&v1", :layer-key "1674603&1674603"}
 {:range-key "veg&2014-06-14T16:16:39.000Z&abs&v1", :layer-key "1674603&1674603"}]
```

What can I do to get faraday deal up all the records?  The source-code suggests that there is some `:last-prim-kvs` option but its not clear to me what would go in there?  The Primary Key on this DDB table is a composite primary key composed of `:layer-key` and `:range-key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it'll fit in memory, this works...

The key to the whole scheme is the getting the opts map set up with a `:limit 99` mapping as well as some `:span-reqs {:max 1}` mapping.  The `:span-reqs` mapping is totally obscure to me, but it seems to be the real driver behind what is conceptually "page size".  I have set up a 10 element table like...

```
;; This only works on the whole table because the table is small!!!!
(far/scan
  common/client-opts
  "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
  {:return #{:part_key :sort_key :note}})
=>
[{:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.abs", :note "\"456\",\"fha.abs\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.rank", :note "\"456\",\"fha.rank\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.raw", :note "\"456\",\"fha.raw\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.true-color", :note "\"456\",\"fha.true-color\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "soil.ssurgo", :note "\"456\",\"soil.ssurgo\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.abs", :note "\"123\",\"fha.abs\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.rank", :note "\"123\",\"fha.rank\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z"}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.raw", :note "\"123\",\"fha.raw\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.true-color", :note "\"123\",\"fha.true-color\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "soil.ssurgo", :note "\"123\",\"soil.ssurgo\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}]
```

If I want to move through this 4 elements at a time, the initial call is...

```
(far/scan
  common/client-opts
  "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
  {:return #{:part_key :sort_key :note}
   :limit 4
   :span-reqs {:max 1}})
=>
[{:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.abs", :note "\"456\",\"fha.abs\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.rank", :note "\"456\",\"fha.rank\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.raw", :note "\"456\",\"fha.raw\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.true-color", :note "\"456\",\"fha.true-color\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}]
```

An all subsequent calls need to set a `:last-prim-kvs {:part_key "xxx" :sort_key "yyy"}` into that opts map to tell faraday where to pick up.  For the 2nd page the call is like...

```
(far/scan
  common/client-opts
  "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
  {:return #{:part_key :sort_key :note}
   :limit 4
   :span-reqs {:max 1}
   :last-prim-kvs {:part_key "456" :sort_key "fha.true-color"}})
=>
[{:part_key "456", :sort_key "soil.ssurgo", :note "\"456\",\"soil.ssurgo\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.abs", :note "\"123\",\"fha.abs\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.rank", :note "\"123\",\"fha.rank\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z"}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.raw", :note "\"123\",\"fha.raw\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}]
```

The last page of my 10 element table is...

```
(far/scan
  common/client-opts
  "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
  {:return #{:part_key :sort_key :note}
   :limit 4
   :span-reqs {:max 1}
   :last-prim-kvs {:part_key "123" :sort_key "fha.raw"}})
=>
[{:part_key "123", :sort_key "fha.true-color", :note "\"123\",\"fha.true-color\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "soil.ssurgo", :note "\"123\",\"soil.ssurgo\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}]
```

Just 2 elements even though I asked for 4.  Trying to far/scan beyond that is always empty.

```
(far/scan
  common/client-opts
  "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
  {:return #{:part_key :sort_key :note}
   :limit 4
   :span-reqs {:max 1}
   :last-prim-kvs {:part_key "123" :sort_key "soil.ssurgo"}})
=> []
```

So this does it end-to-end, provided everything will fit in memory.

```
(loop [accum []
       page (far/scan 
              client-opts 
              "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far" 
              {:limit 4 
               :span-reqs {:max 1}})]
  (if (empty? page)
    accum
    (let [last-on-page (last page)
          last-part-key (:part_key last-on-page)
          last-sort-key (:sort_key last-on-page)]
      (recur
        (into accum page)
        (far/scan
          client-opts
          "users.robert.kuhar.wtf_far"
          {:limit 4
           :span-reqs {:max 1}
           :last-prim-kvs {:part_key last-part-key :sort_key last-sort-key}})))))
=>
[{:part_key "456", :sort_key "fha.abs", :note "\"456\",\"fha.abs\" created 2016-12-08T21:32:20.789Z."}
 ...
 {:part_key "123", :sort_key "soil.ssurgo", :note "\"123\",\"soil.ssurgo\" created 2016-12-08T21:24:30.139Z."}]
```

I think the sad final answer in the case of "How can I get faraday/scan to walk an entire DynamoDB table?" is that it can't.  You need to build it by hand.